# INSERT and then SELECT the inserted row

Tags: mysql, select, insert

My table Structure,Table Name- user_tb

```
User_Id  Name      Mob_No   City
=================================
100      Sumith    34542    dfsc
101      Yadhu     35485    dfgd
102      Aby       34234    jhhg
```

Here column **User_Id** is *auto_increment*
and am inserting values to this table using this query,

```
insert into user_tb(Name,Mob_No,City) values('Yadhu',34542,'dfsc');
```

I need to get User_Id of the Person at the time of insertion
ie, when am inserting using this query,

```
insert into user_tb(Name,Mob_No,City) values('Yadhu',34542,'dfsc');
```

i need to get User_id-101
Is this possible....

Anyone please help me to complete this.

Comment: assuming you are using java , you can use preparedstatement in java

Comment: why don't you just make a select statement after the insert is committed? `Select max(User_Id) from user_tb`?

Comment: use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. See MySQL documents for more http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Answer (score 3):

Obtaining the value of column that uses `AUTO_INCREMENT` after an `INSERT` statement can be achieved in a number of different ways. To obtain the value immediately after an INSERT, use a `SELECT` query with the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function.

For example, using Connector/ODBC you would execute two separate statements, the INSERT statement and the SELECT query to obtain the auto-increment value.

```
insert into user_tb(Name,Mob_No,City) values('Yadhu',34542,'dfsc');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

If you do not require the value within your application, but do require the value as part of another `INSERT`, the entire process can be handled by executing the following statements:

```
insert into user_tb(Name,Mob_No,City) values ('Yadhu',34542,'dfsc');
insert into tbl2 (id,text) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');
```

Comment: Is the behavior above atomic(not affected by _race condition_)?

Comment: It depends on how you're handling your queries. MySQL will namespace each connection, meaning LAST_INSERT_ID()'s context is confined to that specific connection only-- so other connections creating AUTO_INCREMENT values won't be affect/know about your connection's LAST_INSERT_ID() value. Since MySQL will handle your queries sequentially, as long as you order them correctly, it shouldn't create race conditions. However, if you separate the query that generated the AUTO_INCREMENT and the query using LAST_INSERT_ID() into separate connections, this is where you'll run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql: use LAST_INSERT_ID() function; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html

If PHP: use **mysql_insert_id()** to get the last id inserted by your query.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: Did OP mentioned .. he is looking for a PHP answer? I don't see though.

Comment: My mistake, I guess I assumed, added mysql option in my answer